# Are the hat pointers atomic in C++/CX?

Tags: c++-cx

Are the hat pointers (ref pointers) atomic in **C++/CX**? And if no, what are the equivalents of **std::atomic_load** and **std::atomic_store** for them?

And how to make the following code thread-safe?

```
public ref class A sealed { ... };

A ^ p_a = nullptr;
A ^ p_a1 = ref new A();

//thread 1
p_a = p_a1;

//thread 2
p_saved = p_a;
if (p_saved != nullptr)
{
    p_saved->Func();
}
```

For example,

```
std::atomic<A ^> p_a;
```

does not compile.

Comment: The handle-to-object operator ^ is known as a "hat" and is fundamentally a C++ smart pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I am worrying a bit that the pointer itself may be not atomic like int for example, see https://developernote.com/2017/08/cpp-why-int-is-not-atomic/

Comment: That example explicitly writes to non-aligned memory; it's trying very hard to be broken to prove a point. [The read / write of a naturally-aligned pointer should be atomic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx), so you won't get a half-written pointer. But you can't guarantee which happens first, so either `p_saved` will be valid (and the object will have a refcount of 3) or `p_saved` will be `nullptr`.

Comment: Interesting idea, I asked a new question about natural alignment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468186/natural-alignment-volatile-atomic-in-c11